# After updating GLEW, the window became only black

Tags: linux, opengl, debian, glew, debian-buster

After upgrading debian from stretch to buster and updating `GLEW` from `2.0.0-3` to `2.1.0-2`, my application stopped working. More precisely, only the black screen is visible. Shaders compile successfully, but nothing more. Below are excerpts of code from my program:

```
void initGL() {
    std::cout << "Starting GLFW context, OpenGL 3.3" << std::endl;
    // Init GLFW
    if (!glfwInit()) std::cout << "GLFW init failed";
    // Set all the required options for GLFW
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MAJOR, 3);
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MINOR, 3);
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_PROFILE, GLFW_OPENGL_CORE_PROFILE);
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_RESIZABLE, GL_TRUE);

    // Create a GLFWwindow object that we can use for GLFW's functions
    window = FULLSCREEN == true ? 
        glfwCreateWindow(WIN_W, WIN_H, "Algine", glfwGetPrimaryMonitor(), nullptr) : 
        glfwCreateWindow(WIN_W, WIN_H, "Algine", nullptr, nullptr);

    glfwMakeContextCurrent(window);

    // Set the required callback functions
    glfwSetKeyCallback(window, key_callback);
    glfwSetWindowSizeCallback(window, window_size_callback);

    // Set this to true so GLEW knows to use a modern approach to retrieving function pointers and extensions
    // glewExperimental = GL_TRUE;
    // Initialize GLEW to setup the OpenGL Function pointers
    if (glewInit() != GLEW_NO_ERROR) std::cout << "GLEW init failed\n";

    glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
    glDepthMask(true);
    //glCullFace(GL_BACK);
}
```

Rendering:

```
while (!glfwWindowShouldClose(window)) {
    currentTime = glfwGetTime();
    frameCount++;
    // If a second has passed.
    if (currentTime - previousTime >= 1.0) {
        // Display the frame count here any way you want.
        std::cout << frameCount << " fps\n";
        frameCount = 0;
        previousTime = currentTime;
    }

    // Check if any events have been activiated (key pressed, mouse moved etc.) and call corresponding response functions
    glfwPollEvents();
    display();
    glfwSwapBuffers(window);
}
```

I'm using Debian Buster; GLFW + GLEW in my application

Any ideas what the problem might be? I would be very grateful for the help!

**UPDATE:** Rolled back the system to Debian Stretch. After that, I manually updated `glew` to version `2.1.0-2` (which is on Buster) and everything works fine. If the problem is not in the drivers, not in the libraries I use, then it comes out in the Debian Buster itself?

Comment: I added after the `display` function: `std::cout << glGetError() << "\n";`. It returns 0

Comment: Have you tried using debian buster but old glew 2.0.0-3?? Also try creating compatible context.

Comment: I tried to use the old version of glew, but the screen is still black. I also noticed that drawing the geometry does not work completely. Any idea why this is happening? Code: https://codeshare.io/5epxor

Comment: Is it possible that the problem is in the library itself? After all, the version compiled for stretch also worked for buster, and after compiling for buster a black screen. Also, some applications do not work, such as Eclipse

Comment: Rolled back debian to stretch, the problem is not observed. But I'm still looking for a solution to this problem.

Comment: are the same visuals selected for both version?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Problem solved. As it turned out, the problem was in the new `glm`. I manually rolled back the `glm` version from `0.9.9~a2-2`(Buster) to `0.9.8.3-3`(Stretch) and everything began to work as it should.

Comment: [GLM 0.9.9.0 stopped zeroing out (or setting to the identity matrix) default-constructed objects](https://github.com/g-truc/glm/releases/tag/0.9.9.0): "Removed default initialization, use GLM_FORCE_CTOR_INIT to restore the old behavior"